# WebSocket is not a class (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, websocket, ruby-1.9.3

I have some class maintained in one file to run the deamon process. But I am getting 
`lib/web_socket.rb:4:in <top (required)>: WebSocket is not a class (TypeError)` error

I have configured that files like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
require_relative 'lib/web_socket.rb'
require_relative 'app/models/global'
```

And lib web_socket.rb is

```
require "socket"
require 'libwebsocket'

class WebSocket
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Websocket is a module

```
irb(main):001:0> module Websocket
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> class Websocket
irb(main):004:1> end
TypeError: Websocket is not a class
    from (irb):3
    from /home/nicco/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Either you write `module WebSocket` or you write

```
module MyModule
  class WebSocket
    include ::WebSocket
  end
end
```

or this could be of your case

```
class MyWebSocket
   include WebSocket
end
```